# Python if looping only returning final result

Tags: python

I have a very simple issue here but not sure how to resolve it because I am new to Python.
I am writing a code to do calculations using if looping and would like to see the all the results generated by each loop.However, by running my current code below, it is only displaying the final result which should be 1.
Can anyone point out the problem and correct it?

```
n=int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
while n !=1:
    if n % 2 ==0:
        n=n/2
    else:
        n=n*3+1
print n
```

The question above code is writing up for is as following:
given an integer n≥1, if n is even, divide by 2. If n is odd, multiply by 3 and add 1. Repeat this process with the new value of n. As far as anyone can tell, this always ends up with n=1
For example:
Enter a number: 22
22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indent your `print n` statement to put it inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Python works based on indentation, if you have programmed with other languages before you may not have come a cross this. If you don't indent your code properly Python wont understand.

```
n=int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
while n !=1:
    if n % 2 ==0:
        n=n/2
    else:
        n=n*3+1
print n
```

Will run the while loop and at the end print the final answer as you have said.

On the other hand,

```
n=int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
while n !=1:
    if n % 2 ==0:
        n=n/2
    else:
        n=n*3+1
    print n
```

Loops through until n doesn't equal one printing n each time.

Python is one of the few languages that works like this so this won't matter in other languges but does in python.

Comment: the explanation is very detailed, thanks for the ans

Answer (score 1):

The indentation of the last print is wrong. Try this:

```
n=int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
while n !=1:
   if n % 2 ==0:
      n=n/2
   else:
      n=n*3+1
   print n
```